# Show that $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} (\phi(t)^*\alpha) = \mathcal L_{X(t)}\phi(t)^*\alpha$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-derivative

I’m trying to prove equation (1.25) of Remark 1.22 on page 12 of Bennett Chow et al.’s book “Hamilton’s Ricci Flow”:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} (\phi(t)^*\alpha) = \mathcal L_{X(t)}\phi(t)^*\alpha \tag{1.25}$$

where
$$ X(t_0) := \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right\vert_{t=t_0} \left( \phi(t_0)^{-1}\circ \phi(t)\right) = \left(\phi(t_0)^{-1}\right)_*\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right\vert_{t=t_0} \phi(t)$$

However, I’m struggling to write down the Lie derivative $\mathcal L_{X(t)}$ in terms of $\phi (t)$. I reason that if I fix $t=t_0$, I get a vector field $X(t_0)$ and, from it, a flow $\psi(t)$ such that $\left.\frac{d}{dt}\psi(t)\right\vert_{t=0} = X(t_0) = \left(\phi(t_0)^{-1}\right)_*\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right\vert_{t=t_0} \phi(t)$. This means that the RHS of equation (1.25) should be

$$\mathcal L_{X(t_0)} \phi(t_0)^* \alpha = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\epsilon}\left(\psi(\epsilon)^*\phi(t_0)^* \alpha - \phi(t_0)^*\alpha\right)$$

Unfortunately, with this approach, I then get stuck with the term $\psi(\epsilon)^*$.

Comment: Their/your notation is highly confusing. What *is* $X(t)$ for general $t$?

Comment: I’m following their notation. If you substitute $t_0$ with $t$ in the definition of $X$, you get $X(t) =  \left(\phi(t)^{-1}\right)_*\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\right\vert_{a=t} \phi(a)$.

Comment: So what is $X(t)_p$ for any $p\in M$?

Comment: $Y:=\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\right\vert_{a=t} \phi(a)$ is a vector field and $X(t)$ is the pushforward of this vector field by $\left(\phi(t)^{-1}\right)_*$. On a function $g\in C^{\infty}(M)$, $Y$ at $p$ is given by $Y_p (g) = Y(g)(p) = \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\right\vert_{a=t}\phi(a)^*(g)(p) = \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\right\vert_{a=t}g(\phi (a)(p)) = \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\epsilon}\left(g(\phi(a+\epsilon)(p) - g(\phi(a)(p))\right)$. So, $X(t)_p g = \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\right\vert_{a=t}\phi (a)^*\left(g\circ \phi(t)^{-1}\right)(\phi(t)p)$